# Conditionally include a source file

Tags: cmake

In the root CMakeLists.txt I have

```
add_definition(-DMY_MACRO)
```

Then in a sub CMakeLists.txt I want to do something like

```
add_library(mylib, STATIC
    file1
#ifdef MY_MACRO
    file2
#endif
)
```

I tried something like

```
IF( DEFINED MY_MACRO )
SET(FILE2 "file2")
ELSE( DEFINED MY_MACRO )
SET(FILE2 "")
END_IF( DEFINED MY_MACRO )

add_library(mylib static
    file1
    ${FILE2}
)
```

but no joy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add_definitions add a preprocessor definition, it does not define a cmake variable.

I have not tested, but if you really want to look for a preprocessor definition, maybe more something like this:

```
set(mylib_SOURCES )
list(APPEND mylib_SOURCES file1)
get_directory_property(CURRENT_DEFINITIONS COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
list(FIND CURRENT_DEFINITIONS "MY_MACRO" IN_CURRENT_DEFINITIONS)
if(NOT IN_CURRENT_DEFINITIONS EQUAL -1)
    list(APPEND mylib_SOURCES file2)
endif(NOT IN_CURRENT_DEFINITIONS EQUAL -1)
add_library(mylib static ${mylib_SOURCES})
```

(definitions are inherited from parent directories here)

And in your parent CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions(-DMY_MACRO) # should appear before going into subdirectories
add_subdirectory(foo)
```

---

A different approach, based on a variable, would be:

- parent:

  ```
  option(WITH_FOO "with(out) foo option") # or set(WITH_FOO true/false)
  if(WITH_FOO)
      add_definitions(-DMY_MACRO)
  endif(WITH_FOO)
  add_subdirectory(foo)
  ```
- subdirectory:

  ```
  set(mylib_SOURCES )
  list(APPEND mylib_SOURCES file1)
  if(WITH_FOO)
      list(APPEND mylib_SOURCES file2)
  endif(WITH_FOO)
  add_library(mylib static ${mylib_SOURCES})
  ```

Comment: Thanks, you set me on the right track. I just set a cmake variable at the same place the macro is defined. Saves a lot of faff.