# Conditionally include a source file with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I do not really know cmake, but I am trying to setup some sort of an option in CMake - a single line that can be commented or uncommented - and depending on its existence, an additional file should be included in the set of source files.

So, based on:

- [Conditionally include a source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376958/conditionally-include-a-source-file)
- [Negate boolean variable in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773161/negate-boolean-variable-in-cmake)

... I came up with following example `CMakeFiles.txt`:

```
project(MyApp)

option(ADD_EXTRA_FILE TRUE)

set(MyApp_sources
        main.c
        file1.c
        file2.c
)

if(NOT ADD_EXTRA_FILE)
set(MyApp_sources ${MyApp_sources} "extra_file.c")
endif(NOT ADD_EXTRA_FILE)

message(STATUS "ADD_EXTRA_FILE: ${ADD_EXTRA_FILE}")
message(STATUS "MyApp_sources: ${MyApp_sources}")
```

When I run this, I would expect `ADD_EXTRA_FILE` to be `TRUE`, and therefore `if(NOT ADD_EXTRA_FILE)` should evaluate to `FALSE`, and therefore the extra file should *not* be added; however:

```
$ cmake .
-- ADD_EXTRA_FILE: OFF
-- MyApp_sources: main.c;file1.c;file2.c;extra_file.c
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp
```

... it turns out, `ADD_EXTRA_FILE` is `OFF` (?), and apparently `if(NOT ADD_EXTRA_FILE)` evaluates to `TRUE`, and the extra file is added anyways.

Is it possible to achieve what I want in Cmake - and if so, how?

Comment: Consider using `target_sources` for adding sources to a given target. I'd prefer `list(APPEND MyApp_sources extra_file.c)` to add a new element to the source list btw, should you decide to keep using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd personally won't recommend usage of plain `set` for option. @sdbbs did everything right except cleaning cache. If one doesn't provide option manually  it's set once and value won't change after just running `cmake` to reconfigure project.

So the following work as expected:

```
project(MyApp)

option(ADD_EXTRA_FILE "include extra file" ON)

set(MyApp_sources
        main.c
        file1.c
        file2.c
)

if(NOT ADD_EXTRA_FILE)
  set(MyApp_sources ${MyApp_sources} "extra_file.c")
endif(NOT ADD_EXTRA_FILE)

message(STATUS "ADD_EXTRA_FILE: ${ADD_EXTRA_FILE}")
message(STATUS "MyApp_sources: ${MyApp_sources}")
```

with the following output:

```
> cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- ADD_EXTRA_FILE: ON
-- MyApp_sources: main.c;file1.c;file2.c
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

PS

Of course, from the sanity point `ADD_EXTRA_FILE` should be `OFF` by default and `if(ADD_EXTRA_FILE)` adds the file.

Comment: Indeed, that was it - I did not clear the cache; in my case, I was testing with `CMakeFiles.txt` in `/tmp` and with `cmake .`; so to clean the cache, I had to do `rm -rf CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles cmake_install.cmake` - and after that, the `option` works as noted here. However, with `option` I have to remember to clear cache, and with `set` I do not, which is why I like `set` better ...

Comment: 1) why do you create a list of source files ? 2) why you simply didn't use `target_sources(MyApp PRIVATE extra_file.c)` in a `if()` statement or even better, use a generator expression !
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I saw documentation for https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html , and it turns out it accepts values ON or OFF; and the right syntax should be:

```
 option(ADD_EXTRA_FILE "help text" ON)
```

... but even with this setup, I still get printout OFF (?).

So, it turns out, instead of `option()` I should just use `set()` for a plain boolean variable - and then it works as expected. Also, my variable naming logic above is incorrect, so correcting for all that, I get `CMakeLists.txt` which is:

```
project(MyApp)

# set(DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE TRUE)

set(MyApp_sources
        main.c
        file1.c
        file2.c
)

if(NOT DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE)
set(MyApp_sources ${MyApp_sources} "extra_file.c")
endif(NOT DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE)

message(STATUS "DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE: ${DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE}")
message(STATUS "MyApp_sources: ${MyApp_sources}")
```

... and since `set(DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE TRUE)` above is commented, `if(NOT DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE)` also evaluates to TRUE, and the file is added:

```
$ cmake .
-- DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE: OFF
-- MyApp_sources: main.c;file1.c;file2.c;extra_file.c
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp
```

(seemingly, when not otherwise set, `DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE` is seen as an option?)

But if I uncomment that line, `DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE` becomes `TRUE`, the condition `if(NOT DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE)` evaluates to FALSE, and the file is not added, as expected:

```
$ cmake .
-- DONOT_ADD_EXTRA_FILE: TRUE
-- MyApp_sources: main.c;file1.c;file2.c
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp
```

Well, hopefully someone can provide a proper answer - for now, I guess I'll go along with this ...

Comment: regarding you getting `... but even with this setup, I still get printout OFF (?).` you just have to clean cache and run configure from scratch and you see what you expect